# The TextView is not shown and the ScrollView is not scrolling

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I want a sticky TextView above a ScrollView:

The text view should cover 50% of the screen so I set the textview's and the inner linear layout's weight to "1".

But the TextView is not shown at all and the ScrollView is not scrolling!

any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/wallbg"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:height="0dp"
            android:text="Some Text!"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/wallbg"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn1"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                        android:text="Some Text!"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn4"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                        android:text="Some Text!"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn2"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                        android:text="Some Text!"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn3"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                        android:text="Some Text!"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need your `RelativeLayout` at all. Just make your outer `LinearLayout` the root view and set its `layout_height` property to `match_parent` (which is the main issue). Also, the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` should have `wrap_content` for its `layout_height`.